# A finite abelian group in which each element has order 1 or $p$, $p$ prime, is an elementary abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> Prove: a finite abelian group $G$ in which each element has order 1 or $p$, $p$ prime, is an elementary abelian group.

Definition: Let $p$ be a prime number and $n\ge 1$. Then $E_{p^n}:=C_p \times C_p \times\cdots\times C_p$ is an elementary abelian group of order $p^n$.

My attempt:

Let $n=|G|$. Consider $g\ne e \in G$, then $\langle g \rangle \cong C_p \trianglelefteq G$ since $G$ is given to be abelian. Choose $h\ne g\ne e\in G$, and let $x\in \langle g\rangle \cap \langle h\rangle$. Element $x$ has order $p$, thus $\langle x \rangle = \langle g\rangle \cap \langle h\rangle \cong C_p$.

I don't see how I can conclude that $\langle g\rangle \cap \langle h\rangle$ is trivial. Then I'd also have to show that $\prod_{g\in G} \langle g\rangle = G$, to find that $G\cong C_p \times \cdots\times C_p$.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fundamental theorem of FAGs?

Comment: If $\langle x \rangle \cong C_p$, then we must have that $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = \langle g \rangle$, and therefore $h$ is a power of $g$. Thus, the remaining case is when $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = 1$.

Comment: The question does not appear to assume that $G$ is a finite group, but you have assumed that in your proof.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group) says that is the definition of elementary abelian group. What is yours?

Comment: And the wikipedia definition is not just for finite groups.

Comment: I edited my question to give an answer to yours. @ArnaudMortier I am not allowed to use it. It should be proved using properties of direct products, and basic group theoretical results (Lagrange, cyclic groups, normal groups...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $h\notin \langle g\rangle$. Then, by Lagrange's theorem, $\langle g\rangle \cap \langle h\rangle$ is trivial.

If $G$ is finite, then the process of repeatedly choosing elements not in the product that you have at that stage must stop and will give you the direct product you require.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $|G|=p^n$ for some $n$. Take $H\leq G$ with $|H|=p^{n-1}$. Observe $G/H$ is cyclic and let $x\in G$ such that $G/H=\langle xH\rangle$. Consider the map $\phi:H\times G/H\to G$ given by
$$(h,x^kH)\mapsto hx^k.$$
Note that $\phi$ is well defined, since
$$x^kH=x^mH\implies x^{k-m}\in H\implies x^{k-m}\in H\cap\langle x\rangle=\{1\} \implies x^{k-m}=1\implies x^k=x^m.$$

$\phi$ is clearly surjective thus bijective by the finitude of $G$. Moreover it's a group homomorphism:
$$\phi(h,x^kH)\phi(g,x^mH)=(hx^k)(gx^m)=(hg)x^{k+m}=\phi(hg,x^{k+m}H)=\phi((h,x^kH)(g,x^mH)).$$
Hence $G\cong H\times G/H\cong H\times C_p$. Repeat this process with $H$ and so forth until achieving the desired result.